# Comparing 2 complex queries and updating another table based on the comparison results

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 2 complex queries that return the same type and same number of columns as it's output.

**OUTPUT OF QUERY1:**

```
-------------------------------------------
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
-------------------------------------------
```

**OUTPUT OF QUERY2:**

```
-------------------------------------------------
| COL11 | COL22 | COL33 | COL44 | COL55 | COL66 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to update COL_A in TABLE_X when:

```
QUERY1.COL3 == QUERY2.COL33 AND

QUERY1.COL4 == QUERY2.COLL44 AND

QUERY1.COL5 == QUERY2.COLL55 AND

(QUERY1.COL6 == 0) AND (QUERY2.COL66 IS NOT NULL)
```

I did try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEMO AS

  CURSOR Q1 IS
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6 FROM TABLE1;

  CURSOR Q2 IS
    SELECT COL11, COL22, COL33, COL44, COL55, COL66 FROM TABLE2;

  PRESENT BOOLEAN;

  BEGIN
    FOR X IN Q1 LOOP
     PRESENT := FALSE;
     FOR Y IN Q2 LOOP
      IF (X.COL3 = Y.COL33) AND (X.COL4 = Y.COL44) AND (X.COL5 = Y.COL55) AND (X.COL6 = 0 AND Y.COL66 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        PRESENT := TRUE;
        EXIT;
      END IF;
     END LOOP;

     IF PRESENT THEN
        UPDATE TABLE_X SET COL_A = 'Y';
        COMMIT;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;

END DEMO;
/
```

Even though the conditions are satisfying, it's not executing the statements enclosed with the main IF statement.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this comparison and updation?

Thank you so much for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Please share the sample data and expect result.

Comment: [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) is more efficient.